# Failing test for React app component named Hero

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, typeerror, render

I am getting this error for failed test I am getting for react component Hero

My test code is:

```
import React from "react";
import "../App.css"
import {Navbar, Nav, Container}  from 'react-bootstrap';
// import  {NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import myLogo from "../assets/images/icons-bridge-80.png";


function Hero() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <Container className="Container2">
          <Navbar  collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                  <Navbar.Brand  as={Link} to="/"><img data-testid="link" className="logo" src={myLogo} alt="myLogo..."></img></Navbar.Brand>
                  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
              <Nav className="ms-auto">
                  <Nav.Link className="navLink" as={Link} to="/About" ><span>A</span>bout</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link className="navLink" as={Link} to="/Cities"><span>C</span>ities</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link className="navLink" as={Link} to="/Parks"><span>P</span>arks</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link className="navLink" as={Link} to="/Mountains"><span>M</span>ountains</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link className="navLink" as={Link} to="/Beaches"><span>B</span>eaches</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link className="navLink" as={Link} to="/Islands"><span>I</span>slands</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link className="navLink" as={Link} to="/Contact"><span>C</span>ontact</Nav.Link>
                    
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>              
          </Navbar>
        </Container>
      </>
    </div>    
  );
}




export default Hero;
```

Please help!

I tried to render it the same way as I successfully tested & rendered About and Parks components. The test passes if I place <hero /> in '' like:

```
describe('Hero component', () => {
    //First test
    it('renders', () => {
        render('<Hero />');
    });

    
});
```

But it creates no valid snapshot, which I need to test other elements.

Comment: You should be rendering the component itself, not a string: `render(<Hero/>);`

Comment: Yes. When I try the component itself, I get that error and test fails.

Comment: Okay well since that's the right way, give us the error you get when trying to do it the right way. Give all relevant info

Comment: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React__namespace.useContext(...)' as it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering the string  `render('<Hero />')` you should render the `< hero />` component itself.

```
describe('Hero component', () => {
  // First test
  it('renders', () => {
    render(<Hero />);
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes I tried that. It fails.

Comment: with what errors

Comment: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React__namespace.useContext(...)' as it is null.